# Golang parse JSON returns 0

Tags: json, go

The JSON that I am at tempting to parse is very basic and looks like this.

```
{"id": 3, "title":"Test"}
```

The following is the code that I am attempting to use for creating and parsing the JSON.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type Config struct{
    id int
    title string
}

func main() {
    var jsonStr = []byte(`{"id": 3, "title":"Test"}`)
    var conf Config
    err := json.Unmarshal(jsonStr, &conf)
    if err!=nil{
            fmt.Print("Error:",err)
    }
    fmt.Println(conf)
    fmt.Println(string(jsonStr))
}
```

Been looking over a lot of different code examples and can't see what I'm doing wrong.  When I attempt to run this, this is what I get as a return.

```
{0 }
{"id": 3, "title":"Test"}
```

I have verified that the JSON is valid, but continue to get an empty return when attempting to use json.Unmarshal.  Any ideas on what I am missing so that I can get this JSON parsed?

EDIT:  Looks like I can get this to work if I capitalize the titles (Id, Title).  Unfortunately the return I am testing for is a return from an API which returns everything in lowercase.  I need to be able to parse this JSON with lowercase titles as listed above.

Answer (score 3):

Your `Config` struct's fields need to be exported (upper-case), but the keys in your JSON object may remain lower-case.

See here: http://play.golang.org/p/0A5tkCkSO5

Comment: I could have sworn I tried that, but of course it worked perfectly.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Please consult the [JSON package documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/), it is worth the read. While [Amit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26703506/1643939) already addressed the export issue I will address the following:

> EDIT: Looks like I can get this to work if I capitalize the titles (Id, Title). Unfortunately the return I am testing for is a return from an API which returns everything in lowercase. I need to be able to parse this JSON with lowercase titles as listed above.

As you might imagine, the authors of `encoding/json` have thought of that, so again I encourage you to consult the documentation next time. The solution is this ([Example on playground](http://play.golang.org/p/upWPOw0EMA)):

```
type Config struct {
    Id    int    `json:"id"`
    Title string `json:"title"`
}
```

Comment: It's also useful to note the introductory article "JSON and Go": http://blog.golang.org/json-and-go.